# Problema dato Date en metodo jsf

Tags: mysql, jsf, date, jpa, prepared-statements

Puede ser una pregunta tonta pero no he podido solucionar el problema tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
public long contarPedidosMeses(int cedulaCliente, int codigoProducto, Date fechaIni, Date fechaFin){

    Query q;
    q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pedidos, pedidoproducto WHERE fechaDeSolicitud BETWEEN ? AND ? and pedidos.cedulaCliente=? and pedidoproducto.codigoProducto=? and pedidos.idPedido= pedidoproducto.idPedido");
    q.setParameter(1,fechaIni);
    q.setParameter(2, fechaFin);
    q.setParameter(3, cedulaCliente);
    q.setParameter(4, codigoProducto);
    long valor=Long.parseLong(q.getSingleResult().toString());
    return valor;
}


public long valoresMeses(Date fechaI, Date fechaF, int cedula, int codigo){

    long valores= productosf.contarPedidosMeses(cedula, codigo, fechaI, fechaF);
    return valores;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como pasar los datos Date al llamar el método. Por lo tanto la consulta no me resulta bien.

He tratado de la siguiente manera:

```
controladorProducto.valoresMeses('2016/01/01', '2016/01/31', controladorUsuario.objUsuarioLogin.idUsuario, 1)
```

También cambiando el lugar de los números es decir (dd/mm/yyyy), pero tampoco funciona. En el método valoresMeses() he cambiado que no reciba un Date sino un String y trato de convertirlo con SimpleDateFormat pero me manda una fecha muy distinta al convertirlo. No se que mas hacer agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Trabajo en jsf, JPA y la base de datos en MySQL.

Comment: ¿Estás pasando el campo `Date` desde la vista (JSF) o lo estás indicando manualmente? ¿Podrías proveer un ejemplo de cómo vas a utilizar este método?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza El metodo valoresMeses() lo utilizare para pasar los parámetros que necesita la consulta que esta en contarPedidosMeses(). Lo que hará la consulta es contar los registros que hay de entre dos fechas. Al hacer la consulta en la bd funciona perfectamente, pero necesito pasar los campos tipo Date desde la vista como lo mencionas para que cuando lleguen al metodo contarPedidosMeses() lleguen en formato Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus parámetros deben ser de tipo `Date`. Si quieres construir objetos de tipo `Date` a partir de una cadena de texto (para tus pruebas quizás), te recomiendo utilizar `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date fechaI = sdf.parse("2016/01/01");
Date fechaF = sdf.parse("2016/01/31");
int cedula = ...;
int codigo = ...;
valoresMeses(fechaI, fechaF, cedula, codigo);
```

Puedes ahorrarte trabajo al crear métodos utilitarios:

```
//diseño básico, puede ser mejorado
public class MiDateUtils {
    public static Date parseaFecha(String fecha) {
        return parseaFecha(fecha, "yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
    //en caso que necesites utilizar otro formato como dd-MM-yyyy o dd/MM/yyyy o MM/dd/yyyy u otro
    public static Date parseaFecha(String fecha, String formato) {
        Date resultado = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
            resultado = sdf.format(fecha);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //maneja la excepción, mandalo a un log o algo
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Así el código anterior se reduce a:

```
Date fechaI = MiDateUtils.parseaFecha("2016/01/01");
Date fechaF = MiDateUtils.parseaFecha("2016/01/31");
int cedula = ...;
int codigo = ...;
valoresMeses(fechaI, fechaF, cedula, codigo);
```